# mysql - replace value with foreign key automatically on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, foreign-keys

I'm trying to replace a value with its foreign key (from another table), automatically on insert.
I understand the best way to do it is probably with creating a trigger on insert, my first time with triggering.

Example:
Fam_table

```
ID (Key) Family
1        Jordan
2        White

insert into Full_table values ('Adam','white');
```

I want "White" to be replaced with 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without triggers like this

```sql
INSERT INTO full_table
SELECT 'Adam', id
  FROM fam_table
 WHERE family = 'White'
 LIMIT 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50421/1)** demo

Comment: Worked Thanks!!... My example was a bit simple. Any chance you can describe how to do it with a trigger?

Comment: You're quite welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Comment: Now you can't really do this with the trigger, because in that case you'll have to use `VARCHAR` data type for `family` column in `full_table` which is nonsense on its own and won't allow you to use foreign key constraints.